# What word would best represent a combination of being alive, thinking differently, and having atmosphere

Tags: meaning, word-choice, ambiguity, titles

I know it sounds pretty hard to find such a word, but I'm needing a title that flows and is pretty, and attractive. This is a title for a project.

The word I'm trying to think of would try to express to someone the act of thinking differently, or thinking out of the box to a whole new level. In that, it also has to give off the meaning of it being alive (or non-static so to speak). Then on top of that, I also need this title to give off the presence of some aura, atmosphere..perhaps combining this with being alive..establishing the concept of this word representing an experience on many levels. But like I said, on top of it all, the most important part is expressing the idea of thinking off the beaten path and trying to approaching things differently by looking at the bigger picture as a whole and being fresh.

I realize this is relatively complicated and pretty vague so my apologies. I'm struggling just to figure out what exactly I'm looking for. And actually technically because it's such a wide number of meanings for one word, I have the flexibility to have two separate titles if need be.

---

For instance, I'd also go for something like this:

First word: expressing the idea of thinking off the beaten path and trying to approaching things differently by looking at the bigger picture as a whole and being fresh / thinking different, taking out of the box thinking to a new level.

Second word: expressing the atmospheric and being alive part and somehow mixing it with being fresh.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be a single word? Those are three distinct concepts. I've never seen a dictionary definition come even close to being as long as your second paragraph, above. =)

Comment: @migs Yeah unfortunately because it's a title for a project. Like I said, because it's technically two different titles, I figure maybe I could find two separate words that together form something close to that. I know because of the vast span of such a word matching those concepts is very slim, I'm prepared to meet in the middle as far as a word can go. This has been bugging me for a while trying to find a word. Literally years have been spent on this.

Comment: Well, okay, will mull over it. English Language & Usage welcomes you and your chimerical question. (I say this genially, not with irony.)

Comment: This is offtopic unless you explain how it will be used. At the very least you need to explain what part of speech you are after.

Comment: Heterologicalbiooxygenation.

Answer (score 1):

A *pretty and attractive term* which  may come close to what you are looking for is  [cool](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cool). It may suggests liveliness , the effort of being different from others and atmosphere (a cool place).

> - Knowledgeable or aware of the latest trends or developments: spent all his time trying to be cool.
> - Excellent; first-rate: has a cool sports car; had a cool time at the party.
> - Acceptable; satisfactory: It's cool if you don't want to talk about it. (AHD)

Answer (score 0):

**Verve** possibly comes close to portraying a lively essence or atmosphere and an element of originality or individuality.

Note, for example, the archaic meaning of "special ability or talent" that perhaps touches on your concept of thinking differently. Combined with its more common understanding of "energy" and "vitality" it might be what you're after?

> [Mirriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verve)
>   : Full Definition of VERVE 1 archaic :  special ability or talent 2 a : 
>   the spirit and enthusiasm animating artistic composition or
>   performance :  vivacity b :  energy, vitality

---

Okay - I can't add comments so I'll update this answer given that Verve is not an option. I think, perhaps, that the real challenge is finding a word that is available as well as suitable (as if the latter isn't challenging enough when trying to deploy an original project!).

What about **Trailblazer**? It's relatively uncommon, so hopefully available for your project, has clear connotations of originality and is quite dynamic (well, at least it touches on the 'lively' aspect you're seeking).

Plus, as composite of two words you can make it more visually appealling by capitalising the *b*:

### **TrailBlazer**

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to use the word Verve. I was thinking about that one as well by happenstance. But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Please tell us why you cannot use "verve"?

Comment: If you'll accept three short words: Vibrant and quirky?

Comment: @littleeva This is a search for the name of the project I'm working on and Verve cannot be used because it's in use by another person.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are describing an *awakening*. This is used figuratively—not an actual waking up, but a *transformation* wherein one  suddenly becomes vibrantly aware of situations or opportunities that one had not considered before.

Another similar word is *epiphany*.